# On hover: Move div up, on top of sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following setup:

```
<div class="" style="height: 400px !important;
                     width: 100% !important;
                     overflow: hidden;">
  <div class="" style="height: 400px !important;
                       width: 100% !important;
                       background-color: red;">
  </div>
  <div class="" style="height: 400px !important;
                       width: 100% !important;
                       background-color: blue;">
  </div>
</div>
```

So there's a div, which has a certain height. There are two divs inside it which have the same height, which means that their height together is twice as much as their container div. Overflow is hidden, so only the first div is showing.

I now want to wait for the user to hover, then animate and move the second div up, so that the second div is hiding the first div now. On unhover, I want to revert the whole thing.

How would I do something like this, am I on the right track?

Comment: Hi George, what is the code you already tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use CSS transforms for this. When hovering the container div a transform is applied to the inner divs.

The transition rule is used to show the change in position when a hover starts and stops.

```css
.container {
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container:hover .inner-2 {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.inner {
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
}

.inner-1 {
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.5);
}

.inner-2 {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255,.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner inner-1"></div>
  <div class="inner inner-2"></div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jekvusLj/1/)

It's worth noting that this method is much less processor intensive than the answers suggesting absolute positioning the element or changing its margin and will also result in a much smoother transition.

Sources: https://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/ and https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/

Comment: Thank you! That's already really helpful! However, I do not want to move both divs up at the same time, but move the lower div up, and then overlap & hide the upper div, i.e., strictly speaking I do not want to move the first div up, just hide it underneath the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to reach nice animation when you overflow container, code below just swap them on hover:

CSS

Default state

```
   div>div:first-child {
      display: block;
   }

   div>div:last-child {
      display: none;
   }
```

Hover state

```
   div:hover>div:first-child {
      display: none;
   }

   div:hover>div:last-child {
      display: block;
   }
```

Alternative height rising

```css
div {
   position: relative;
 }

 div>div:first-child {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    
 }

 div>div:last-child {
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 0 !important;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: height .5s linear;
 }

div:hover>div:last-child {
    height: 400px !important;
 }
```

```html
<div class="" style="height:400px !important; width:100% !important; overflow:hidden;">
      <div class="" style="height:400px; width:100% !important; background-color: red;">
      </div>

      <div class="" style="height:400px; width:100% !important; background-color: blue;">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are on the right track. I would advise to not use [inline styles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/style) though, but instead use [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) and [CSS markup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#Examples).

You can use for example the margin for offsetting. This can be animated using [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition).
I show this below.

```css
.parent {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.parent:hover .child:first-child {
  margin-top: -100px;
}

.child {
  height: 100px;
  transition: margin-top 1s;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child red">
  </div>
  <div class="child blue">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can use CSS alone. If you wrap the child divs in another `div` which has it's `margin-top` animated when the container `div` is hovered, something like this:

```css
.container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
.slide {
  margin-top: 0;
  transition: margin 0.3s;
}
.container:hover .slide { margin-top: -400px; }
.child.red { background-color: red; }
.child.blue { background-color: blue; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="child red"></div>
    <div class="child blue"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively you can just shrink the `height` of the first div, but this can cause overflow issues, depending on what the content of that element is:

```css
.container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: height 0.3s;
}
.container:hover :first-child { height: 0; }
.child.red { background-color: red; }
.child.blue { background-color: blue; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child red"></div>
  <div class="child blue"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8uyp5mc6/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="container" style="height:400px !important; width:100% !important; overflow:hidden;">
  <div class="top" style="height:400px !important; width:100% !important; background-color: red;">
  </div>

  <div class="bottom" style="height:400px !important; width:100% !important; background-color: blue;">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container:hover .bottom{
  top: -400px;
}

.bottom{
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  transition-property: top;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

The bottom div inside the container is relatively positioned and moves to the top when the container has the hover state.